# Placing span and wicket:message together in next line

Tags: html, css, wicket

I have a td [table data] in which I'm placing span tag with Text as "Crocin 650 MG" , wicket:message with text "Qty" and 1 more span tag with text as "8". 
All these are coming in 1 single line.

When text length increases, only 8 wraps in 2nd line. I want to move both "Qty" and "8" in next line after wrap, not only 8.

```html
<td wicket:id="testing" class="label">
    <strong><span wicket:id="dosage">Crocin 650 90MG, </span></strong>
    <wicket:message key="Qty" />
    <span wicket:id="quantity">8</span>
</td>
```

After that , there are some other table data as well.

Class label is as follows:

```css
label {
    width: 32%;
    padding-left: 22px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-right: 22px;
}
```

Output is :

> Crocin 650 90MG, Qty
>
> 8

I want this Output as :

> Crocin 650 90MG, 
>   Qty 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to wrap the quantity and the number in an additional `<span>` and add `white-space: nowrap;` to it:

```
<td wicket:id="testing" class="label">
    <strong><span wicket:id="dosage">Crocin 650 90MG, </span></strong>
    <span style="white-space: nowrap;"><wicket:message key="Qty" /><span wicket:id="quantity">8</span></span>
</td>
```

Comment: Are you sure that wicket:message can be wrapped inside span tag? It is throwing error in Eclipse.